# How to learn time series by myself

Tags: soft-question, time-series

I would like to learn time series by myself. Could anyone introduce a beginner/introduction book to me so I could have a basic idea of that.

Also, is there any background requirement for that class?

Thanks!

Comment: Background requirements for _which_ class? And what part of the potentially infinite amount of things there are to say about "time series" (which is not a terribly informative term in the first place) do you want to end up knowing?

Comment: I am thinking of taking a grad level Time Series in Eco department. I have background in math and Computer Science. I would like to know time series for prediction. Will you have any idea on that?

Comment: What is "Eco department"? It sounds like you're talking about a particular course offered by a particular institution of learning, but you're expecting us to either guess or know by telepathy which institution that is ...

Comment: Time series in this context is stuff plotted against time (like stock prices, interest rates, etc.)?

Comment: Rue Tsay's "Analysis of financial time series".

Comment: Yep!! Stock prices, something like that...